# AXIS Media Control ActiveX component

Tags: c#, winforms, video, activex

I have an ActiveX control that plays streaming video, 
that i download from: http://www.axis.com/techsup/cam_servers/dev/activex.htm 
My goal is to draw a Ellipse on the video!!
i create form (winform) that use this ActiveX control and i see the video,
but the video dominate the screen and every thing that i try to put on the video, never seen.
any help?

```
amc.mediaurl="192.168.0.1";
amc.mediatype="mpjg";
amc.play();
```

Comment: Have you managed to achieve what you were asking for ?

Answer (score 2):

That control should have properties in order to set the screenplay dimension, you should check the documentation. I've played with Axis control months ago, so I'm pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

To draw ellipses, Polygon and other shapes on a Axis Media Control video stream, you have to use the *UserObject* methods set with overlays:

`BeginUserObject`, `EndUserObject`, `GetUserObject`, `SetUserObject`, `RemoveUserObject`, `OnUserObjectChanged`.

There is a help file, `AmcDoc.chm`, in the directory where the AMC is installed. It is usually in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Axis Communications\AXIS Media Control SDK\doc`.

SetUserObject is used to draw things over the video stream:

```
  HRESULT SetUserObject(ByVal theID As Long,
            ByVal theType As Long,
            ByVal theData As String,
            ByVal theName As String,
            ByVal theColor1 As Long,
            ByVal theColor2 As Long,
            ByVal theNumPointsLimit As Long,
            ByVal theFlags As Long)
```

For example, to draw an Ellipsis :

```
axAxisMediaControl1.SetUserObject(2, 4, 
                                  "4500,4500,500,1000", "test", 
                                  255, 100, -1, 19);
```

> The first two integers defines the center point of the ellipse (x,y). The third integer defines the radius relative to the x axis of the circle. The fourth  integer defines the radius relative to the y axis of the circle.

For this to work, you have to set `enableOverlays` to 1 in the media control properties.